# Find first unused number in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a solution to find an unused number in the table. The most of the solutions I came across so far is creating a temporary table with all the numbers and used left join to find the unused number. In my case, I have no opportunity to create a temporary table.

The number range with leading zeros: `0001-1999`. These numbers are dialing pad numbers and it has to be 4 digits in length.

listings table:

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | title  | pad_number |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 | Foo    |       0001 |
|  2 | bar    |       0005 |
|  3 | Baz    |       1999 |
| 10 | FooBar |       0002 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

Expected result:

```
0003
```

Is there any way to retrieve the number?

Comment: first unused number based on the order of number or something else?

Comment: All I need to get a number which is unsued.

Comment: I am confused by the combination of statements: _"The number range with leading zeros"_ **and** _"So leading zeros not optional"_

Comment: @Brien Removed the extra sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as:

```
select lpad(min(pad_number) + 1, 4, '0')
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.pad_number = t.pad_number + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`.

```
select lpad(cast(cast(pad_number as unsigned)+1 as char(4)),4,'0')
from tbl t
where not exists (select 1 from tbl t1 
                  where cast(t.pad_number as unsigned)=cast(t1.pad_number as unsigned)-1)
and cast(pad_number as unsigned) >=0 and cast(pad_number as unsigned) < 1999
order by 1
limit 1
```

Comment: Is there any way to match the number from a range? i.e 0001-1999.

Comment: sure..use a `where` condition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Somehow, the query not returning `0001` if not exists.